# Как лучше реализовать C++ класс для хранения разнотипных данных?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу реализовать класс `Value` для хранения данных абсолютно произвольного типа, но так, чтобы хранить в одном массиве экземпляры этого класса (поэтому не подходит шаблонный класс). Сейчас в классе имею указатель `void*`, строку, в которой хранится название типа и пару шаблонных-функций членов для записи/доступа к данным в `void*`, где параметры шаблонов - типы, они посредством `typeid` сравниваются со строкой, и если совпадают, то можно читать/писать, иначе - генерируется исключение.

Мне не очень нравится такое решение, производительность плохая, да и выглядит отвратно.

Есть идея сделать в этом классе вместо `void*` и строки с типом шаблонную функцию, которая при первом вызове создает что-то типа `static T* ptr = new T()`, а при следующих вызовах сравнивает тип этого статического указателя с типом в параметре шаблона посредством `std::is_same<...>`.

Можете посоветовать какое-нибудь решение или модификацию для имеющихся? Важна простота и производительность. Смотрел какую-то библиотеку json, там был похожий класс, но он мог хранить только данные определенных типов, а чтобы до них корректно можно было добраться, надо было использовать методы типа `is_number()`. Поэтому я хочу разработать решение, в котором если мы показываем экземпляру класса `Value`, что знаем, данные какого типа он хранит, то только в этом случае получаем к ним доступ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример реализации с [Хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/207294/):

```
class any
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    any(const T& t) : held_(new holder<T>(t)){}
    ~any(){ delete held_; }
    template<typename U>
    U cast() const
    {
        if(typeid(U) != held_->type_info())
            throw std::runtime_error("Bad any cast");
        return static_cast<holder<U>* >(held_)->t_;
    }
private:
    struct base_holder
    {
        virtual ~base_holder(){}
        virtual const std::type_info& type_info() const = 0;
    };

    template<typename T> struct holder : base_holder
    {
        holder(const T& t) : t_(t){}
        const std::type_info& type_info() const
        {
            return typeid(t_);
        }
        T t_;
    };
private:
    base_holder* held_;
};

int main() 
{
    any a(2);
    std::cout << a.cast<int>() << std::endl;
    any b(std::string("abcd"));
    try
    {
        std::cout << b.cast<double>() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно посмотреть в сторону [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). По-моему, как раз под вашу задачу. Совсем недавно данный класс перекочевал из экспериментальных классов библиотеки в основные.

Накидал пример ([онлайн](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5Y4GqxVGstZbtnKG)):

```
#include <any>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, std::any any) {
  if (any.type() == typeid(std::string)) stream << std::any_cast<std::string>(any); else
  if (any.type() == typeid(int)) stream << std::any_cast<int>(any); else 
  if (any.type() == typeid(float)) stream << std::any_cast<float>(any); else throw std::runtime_error("Bad cast");
  return stream;
}

int main() {
  try {  
    std::vector<std::any>Any;
    Any.push_back(std::string("Строка"));
    Any.push_back(10);
    Any.push_back(1.2f);
    for(const auto &i:Any) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;  
  } catch(std::runtime_error &e) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;  
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Some error" << std::endl;  
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Только следует учесть, что `std::any` реализован в С++17. До этого стандарта нужно смотреть в сторону [`std::experimental::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any).

Comment: А примеры его использования есть где-то? И есть ли информация по его реализации? А то вдруг он как раз через typeid работает...

Comment: Отредактировал ответ. Да, typeid там используется.